# How to insert all these details in the database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have an application where the user can write up some questions and add it in a table row in the application (each question goes into each row). After user has finished writing up their questions then they can add these questions into a database.

Now If the user only has one question to add in the database then this is fine because when I INSERT this in the database, it inserts the question in the database.

The problem though is that if the user has 2 or more questions to insert in the database, it only inserts the latest question in the database row and not both questions.

So for example if I have 1 question (what is 2+2) in the application table row, then this is what it will display below in the database:

```
SessionId    QuestionContent

SAS          What is 2+2
```

But if I have 2 question (what is 2+2 and what is 3+3) in the application table row, then this is what it will display below in the database:

```
 SessionId    QuestionContent

    SAS          What is 3+3
```

The above is incorrect as it only displays the latest question and not both questions. It should display this below in the database:

```
 SessionId    QuestionContent

    SAS          What is 2+2
    SAS          What is 3+3
```

So what my question is how can I Insert all the questions in the database like above in the database?

Below is the INSERT VALUES code I currently have:

```
     <?php

            mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

            mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

                     $insertquestion = array();

    foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $question)
    {
        $insertquestion[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . "' , ' ".     mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) . "'";
    }

      $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionContent) 
      VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";



    mysql_query($questionsql);

            mysql_close();

        ?>
```

Below is the full code for you to see how a question is added using javascript and html. Follow it carefully and you will understand how a question is appended or added into a table row:

```
        <script>

        function insertQuestion(form) {

        var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
            var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
            var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");

         $('#questionTextArea').each( function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                       .attr('value',$this.val())

        $question.append($questionText);

        });


        $tr.append($question);
        $tbody.append($tr); 

        }

        </script>

        <body>

        <form id="QandA" action="insertQuestion.php" method="post" >

<h1>SESSION (<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?>)</h1>

        <table id="question">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
            <td rowspan="3">
                <textarea id="questionTextArea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <p><input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" /></p>

        <hr/>


        <table id="qandatbl" align="center">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="question">Question</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>


        <p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" /></p>

        </form> 

        </body>
```

Comment: First thing you should do is check the obvious. First make sure the generated sql is correct for multiple values. So instead of running the query in your program, just print it out and run it directly in mysql. Also if you could post your schema, it may help. But from first glance everything looks ok.

Comment: I did an echo on my query and after typing in 2 questions, it did the same thing and only echoed the latest question and not both questions. It echo this below: `INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionContent) VALUES (' WNQ' , ' what is 2+2') `

Comment: The initial issue looks like you have no loop for your values.

Comment: I have added the code on how the questions are added at the bottom of my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell you'll only ever have 1 element in your $insertquestion array:

```
$insertquestion[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . "' , ' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['questionText'] ) . "'";
```

This inserts one element.  When you implode this array there's only one element so it's the same as $insertquestion[0].

What does your HTML form look like that allows you to enter multiple questions?  Are you using multiple form fields for that or putting multiple questions into one form field?  If it's the latter then you'll first need to separate those questions and push each one into $insertquestion.

EDIT
Based on your HTML/JS code the problem is that you insert each new textarea with the same name.  When the form is submitted, duplicate named elements are grouped and this results in only the last element with that name showing up in your $_POST array

To fix this you can append "[]" to the name of the elements.  By doing so, the $_POST array for that name will contain an array.

So in your javascript code change it to this:

```
var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'</textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]").attr('value',$this.val())
```

And then in your PHP:

```
$insertquestion = array();

foreach($_POST['questionText'] as $question)
{
    $insertquestion[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['id'] ) . "' , ' ".     mysql_real_escape_string( $question ) . "'";
}

  $questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionContent) 
  VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";
```

That will loop through the $_POST['questionText'] array and insert each element of that array (i.e. each question) into the $insertquestion array.  After that you're good to go.

Comment: I will post you what code looks like when adding a question, it required both javascript and html. I will post the code, give me 10 mins :)

Comment: I have added the code on how the questions are added at the bottom of my question :)

Comment: I will test this and get back to you if it works or not. Thanks, I will be bout 10 mins to test it

Comment: Hi, I tested it but it did not quite work. But there is a change, instead of inserting the latest question which has been entered into the database, it is now posting whatever the first question was entered into the database e.g. if I have 2 questions and first one was 'what is 1+1' and second was 'what color is the sky', the database will insert the 'what is 1+1' question into the database only

Comment: I have updated the php code where the query occurs and the javascript code where the rows are appended.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code then replaced the mysql stuff with an echo of your sql query - the output I got is INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionContent) VALUES (' ' , ' what is a and b'), (' ' , ' what is 3 and 2').  Looks correct to me.

Comment: (Note: the SessionID values in the query are blank as I haven't set up a session in my test code)

Comment: The sessionId is simply the name  of the session which is in the form code which I have just included now when updating the code.

Comment: In my echo it shows this : INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionContent) VALUES (' DWR' , ' my name is'), (' DWR' , ' my age is') . So the echo works, i just don't know why it only displays 1 row in the database showing only 1 question?

Comment: Without seeing your db schema and entire codebase the only guess I can hazard is that the SessionId field in your db is set as a unique key or primary key in which case you can only have one "DWR" entry.

Comment: I sent you an email but ignore that. You sre right, the reason it is only adding 1 row is that I have composite keys which are SessionId and QuestionId, as I havn't inserted a questionId yet which is a question number, it only outputs sessionid and as you can only have 1 session 'DWF', only 1 row is added. I understand what I need to do, I need to insert question number as well now. Thanks for your help :) This problem is fixed :)